# Adding uploaded images to editor from metabox instead of default popup uploader

Tags: metabox, uploads, thumbnails

I need to find plugin or create listing of all uploaded images for some post in custom metabox. And i can click to thumbnail for add image to editor in custom format.

I downloaded a lot of photos to default upload box, and each time i will do a lot of clicks for insert new image to editor. It is very uncomfortable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Faster Image Insert](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/faster-image-insert/)?

> Moves built-in Media Manager down in a meta-box, right next to main
>   editing panel, so you have full control of the manager: opens it,
>   makes it collapse or hidden from the interface completely.
>
> Best of all, is now you can insert image(s) much faster, and precisely
>   where you want them to be.

Answer (score 7):

New WP (3.3+) uses plupload, which we now fully integrated into [RW Meta Box](https://github.com/rilwis/meta-box).

#### Examples

[image]

<sup>The basic meta box before any file was via drag & drop.</sup>
[image]

<sup>Plupload during upload - Status "loading/error" have background images for a clean UI.</sup>
[image]

<sup>The "Uploaded Images" title appears only on demand.</sup>

#### Customize

---

The "TITLE string" headline (hndle bar) can be set during setup of the meta box.

---

The "drag & drop file here" string is customizable with the following filter:

```
function alter_drop_string( $string )
{
    return __( 'drag &amp; drop whatever here', 'YOUR TEXTDOMAIN' );
}
add_filter( 'rwmb_upload_drop_string', 'alter_drop_string' );
```

This filter changes the string of *all* Plupload meta boxes, so you should care about checking `$GLOBALS['hook_suffix']` and output a different string for your post/page/CPT.

Comment: Definitely a vote up!

Comment: @kaiser, the RW Meta Box is great, but what if I only want add the media upload field to my custom post type? I already create my own custom meta with my own,now I only lacks of image field. Any guidelines of tutorial?

Comment: Why not use the RW Meta Box lib? Easy to setup, constant development, etc.

Comment: @kaiser Is it possible to add an "insert into post" button, much like the regular uploader works?

Comment: @INT Sorry, but I don't know. You could simply use `submit_button();` and use your own custom javascript that fires on `click`. Then insert whatever shortcode you built to display that image(s).