# How to allow the user to add an arbitrary amount of post thumbnails

Tags: post-thumbnails

I already installed [Multiple Post Thumbnails](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/multiple-post-thumbnails/installation/). However I would like to allow the user to decide how many images he associates with the post (or rather page in my special case).

I could of course just define a ridiculously high amount of post thumbnails and ignore the unset ones in the template. However that just doesn't seem right and would unnecessarily clutter the "Create Page" interface

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adding uploaded images to editor from metabox instead of default popup uploader](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/38250/adding-uploaded-images-to-editor-from-metabox-instead-of-default-popup-uploader)

Comment: @Bainternet class is basically a fork of the RW Meta Box Class. The process how to generate a meta box with the new Plupload Drag & Drop Interface, gets described in the linked Q/A.

Answer (score 2):

You can create you own metabox with the option to images as many as you want and use that as post thumbnails.

you can use [**`my metabox class`**](http://en.bainternet.info/2012/how-i-add-a-wordpress-metabox) and with an image field inside a repeater block you get something like this:

[image]

Comment: Looks good, I'll give it a try