# Upload multiple images and insert them into custom html code

Tags: plugin-development, images, uploads, media-library

Good evening. :)

Well, my mother is currently using a wordpress installation for her day to day blogging.
Often, a post consists of some text and a few images, which are displayed via the very nice [flexslider script](http://flex.madebymufffin.com/).
Usually, when the post is ready, I handle the flexslider part.
However, I'm not always around, so posts get delayed, I get calls...
You know. :)
I'd like her to be able to do it herself, so I was thinking about writing a quick and dirty little plugin.

Basically, just select some images from the library and paste the code into the editor.
Nothing fancy, this shouldn't take longer than a night or so.

The problem is, I've never developed anything wordpress, so some tips would be greatly appreciated.
Of course, I'm not afraid of reading the documentation, but I don't have the time to really dive into it right now.

Thanks for your time. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just take a look at the [`RW_Meta_Box`](https://github.com/rilwis/meta-box) library to add a drag and drop interface to add images as post meta data. That's the most easiest approach, plus it uses the new »WP Pluploader«. For more details take a look at [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/38250/adding-uploaded-images-to-editor-from-metabox-instead-of-default-popup-uploader/38257#38257) on how to customize it and read a little in the TenderApp Knowledgebase for a how-to.